# Using Percona pt-query-digest to analyse slow query log for a specific database only

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-slow-query-log, pt-query-digest

Percona tool script, pt-query-digest, looks like it will be very useful to analyse a MySQL slow query log.
Does someone know how I can get the script to only look at queries relating to a specific database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pt-query-digest --filter '$event->{db} eq "mydatabase"' ...other arguments...
```